# Grub2 and Windows 7 & Vista

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, windows-vista

I would like to triple boot... don't ask why ;-)...

I have Ubuntu 13.10 and ghost copy of W7 and Vista installation. Would like to be able to boot all three OS from the same partition.

The problem is that it wont boot both the Vista and 7. I think the issue is related to the guid on the partition. And that systemreserved partition that both Windows versions have.

I would like to end up with Grub2 managing all three OSes but I don't want Windows' own boot manager knowing and showing the other OS in its boot menu. If I would start Windows 7 then it will only boot it, same with Vista.

Comment: Pleas [edit] your question and explain 1) your partitioning scheme 2) which OS is in which partition 3) where is GRUB installed 4) what options does GRUB offer you 4) what happens when you choose each of them. As it stands, it is impossible to understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

In 1st step make 3 partitions for all your system, but (because u need disable partitions)  i think better would be when u get 2 'hdd' to install on 1st Ubuntu and to 2nd windows

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1664134

```
sudo apt-get install grub2
```

Answer (score 0):

More of a Windows install issue than this forums Ubuntu with grub.

The Windows boot loader only knows one primary partition to boot from. In Linux we see that as the boot flag, in Windows it is the active partition. All installs of Windows will put boot files into that one active partition.

If you install each Windows in a separate primary NTFS partition with the boot flag at the time of install, it will keep its boot files. Or you may be abel to move boot flag and do repairs to restore boot files. If second install is in a logical partition it may not be possible.

Then from grub you can direct boot each Windows install. But the Windows boot loader if restored to the MBR, would only boot one install or the other depending on which has boot flag.

Pictures here worth 1000+ words - Vista but all Windows with BIOS/MBR

http://www.multibooters.co.uk/multiboot.html